# ARIMA.from_formula with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, time-series

Currently, I am trying to do a seasonal ARIMA model with a 2nd order autoregressive model, a 60 day lag, and a non stationary model. When I input my formula, dataframe, and time index into the function, it returns an error. I am confused with this function because I know that I need to input the order (p,q,d) into the function somehow, but its parameters doesn't specify it. Here is my code below:

```
 wue_formula = ' WUE ~ 1 + SFO3 + PAR + Ta + VPD'

 model = tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.from_formula(wue_formula,gs_residual_df,subset = gs_residual_df.index)


File "<ipython-input-67-d518e1f9e7cc>", line 1, in <module>
tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.from_formula(wue_formula,gs_residual_df,subset =    gs_residual_df.index)

File "/Users/JasonDucker/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 99, in from_formula
mod = cls(endog, exog, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JasonDucker/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py", line 872, in __new__
p, d, q = order

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Statsmodel's website has been down the past few days and I cant read the documentation for this to understand my problem fully. Some help with this code would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: My guess right now is that `from_formula` is not supported and it's only there because it's inherited. At least, I also don't get a simple example to work. Explanatory variables in ARMA and ARIMA were a later addition and before that there was no reason to support `from_formula`. This needs an issue on github for statsmodels and needs to be looked into. temporary work around use patsy.dmatrix to create the design matrix (exog).

Comment: I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2547 to track this.